# Firebase: Add value to array without possibly overwriting

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a messaging app with with models looking like this

```
public class Message {
    String message;
    List<String> reads;

    ... more logics
}
```

On firebase it looks like this

```
... [ 
   "myGeneratedMessageId" : {
       "from":"userId1",
       "reads":[
          "userId2",
          "userId3"
       ]
   }, ...

]
```

When a user sees it the user's id should be added to the array. Will I have to worry about overwriting values in that array if multiple users are seeing it simultaneously? And what do I do to make that not happening?

For clarification,

User 1 sees the message -> sends the user id to that array (I guess by adding it to the local array and then updating that child on the message on Firebase)

User 2 sees the message before User 1 updates it, updating it too - with adding only his id to the array and updating the child on Firebase

### Edit: Updated usage (potential problem still exists)

I made `reads` into a hashmap with `id : boolean`

```
 ... 
 "message": "Hello world!",
 "from": "userId1",
 "reads":[
     "userId2": true,
     "userId3": true
 ], ...
```

Inside model `markAsRead()`

```
if(reads == null) {
   reads = new HashMap<String, Boolean>(); <-- could cause problem
} 

if(reads.get(userId) == null) {
   reads.put(userId, true);
}

.. save logics
```

A user could still **create** the hashmap if there is none, making the other users' new hashmap rewrite it.

Comment: The potential for multi-user conflicts is large when using arrays. This is one of the many reasons why [Firebase recommends against using arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and [proposes a different way to handling list structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#read_and_write_lists). But what you have looks like it might be [better served with a set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value), which very conveniently solves the problem you outline.

Comment: I think the problem will be avoided if you made changes (when user read) directly into database, without adding it into your local `HashMap` first. I mean by using `...getReference("myGeneratedMessageId/reads/" + user.getUid).setValue(true)`. And since the message object is continuously synced, the value of read `HashMap` will also be updated

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you are worried about concurrent updates on your firebase database.

If that so, you can check the section

[Save data as transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)

And check this answer:

[Firebase - Multiple users simultaneously updating same object using its old value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689663/firebase-multiple-users-simultaneously-updating-same-object-using-its-old-valu)